# How to set TODAY as default date for a custom date field placed on a contribution page?

Tags: custom-fields, profile, extension, contribution-page

How to set default date today on a custom date field that is added on a contribution page via profile?

I have tried to add this in my extension but doesnt seem to work and getting populated as 01/01/1970 set after form submitted
.
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
function club_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
    if ($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main'
        && in_array($form->getVar('_id'), [42])
      ) {
        $defaultDate = date("d/m/Y");
        $defaults['custom_315'] = $defaultDate;
        $form->setDefaults($defaults);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Its should be  $defaultDate = date("Ymd");

Comment: !thanks @PradeepNayak-CircleInt. it worked with build form function as well now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by including this JS snippet in the extension instead, posting here incase it helps someone.

```
var now = new Date();
var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;
$('#custom_315').val(today);
```

EDIT: It also works with following build form function, Thanks to Pradeep for the hints.

```
    function club_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
        if ($formName == 'CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution_Main'
            && in_array($form->getVar('_id'), [42])
          ) {
           //Populate Date using the function
            $defaultDate = date("Ymd");
            $defaults['custom_315'] = $defaultDate;
            $form->setDefaults($defaults);
           //alternatively addScriptFile function to inject js
            Civi::resources()->addScriptFile('club', 'club.js');
          }
        }
```